# If column AD=1 then Copy content of B to C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file and I want for every row to check if AD is 1 then from this row copy the content of B to C.

How to do that?

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service. It's purpose is for coders to help other coders (even if the asker is a complete novice). That means you need to make an attempt, show your work, and explain why it's not working and/or not doing as you'd hoped. In this case it's probably also sensible to include images or tables showing a subset of the source data and the desired result (i.e. what it looks like before and after).

Answer (score 0):

formula to put into C2:

=if(AD2=1,B2,"")

and then fill down